# If found a pattern, how to paste the last line before that contain another pattern in bash?

Tags: bash, sed, replace, gsub

After put a list of all folders and subfolders in a `list.txt` with the command `ls -R`, I have this kind of data:

```
 Invertebrates/Phylum_echinoderma/Class_Echinoidea/Fam_Diadematidae/Sp_01:
 DSCF0214.JPG
 DSCF0215.JPG
 DSCF0231.JPG

 Invertebrates/Phylum_echinoderma/Class_Echinoidea/Fam_PasDiadematidae:
 Sp_02
 Sp_03

 Invertebrates/Phylum_echinoderma/Class_Echinoidea/Fam_PasDiadematidae/Sp_02:
 DSCF8981.JPG
 DSCF8988.JPG

 Invertebrates/Phylum_echinoderma/Class_Echinoidea/Fam_PasDiadematidae/Sp_03:
 DSCF0638.JPG

 Invertebrates/Phylum_echinoderma/Class_Holothuroidea/Fam_Stichopodidae:
 Sp_07

 Invertebrates/Phylum_echinoderma/Class_Holothuroidea/Fam_Stichopodidae/Sp_07:
 DSCF0724.JPG
```

I would like to add a line code that which will allow to add the path before the pictures ("XXX.JPG").
So I tried to say in bash: "if there is the ".JPG" pattern, paste before the picture name the "last line before" that contain "/Sp*". And replace `:` by `/`.
In order to obtain this:

```
 Invertebrates/Phylum_echinoderma/Class_Echinoidea/Fam_Diadematidae/Sp_01:
 Invertebrates/Phylum_echinoderma/Class_Echinoidea/Fam_Diadematidae/Sp_01/DSCF0214.JPG
 Invertebrates/Phylum_echinoderma/Class_Echinoidea/Fam_Diadematidae/Sp_01/DSCF0215.JPG
 Invertebrates/Phylum_echinoderma/Class_Echinoidea/Fam_Diadematidae/Sp_01/DSCF0231.JPG

 Invertebrates/Phylum_echinoderma/Class_Echinoidea/Fam_PasDiadematidae:
 Sp_02
 Sp_03

 Invertebrates/Phylum_echinoderma/Class_Echinoidea/Fam_PasDiadematidae/Sp_02:
 Invertebrates/Phylum_echinoderma/Class_Echinoidea/Fam_PasDiadematidae/Sp_02/DSCF8981.JPG
 Invertebrates/Phylum_echinoderma/Class_Echinoidea/Fam_PasDiadematidae/Sp_02/DSCF8988.JPG

 Invertebrates/Phylum_echinoderma/Class_Echinoidea/Fam_PasDiadematidae/Sp_03
 Invertebrates/Phylum_echinoderma/Class_Echinoidea/Fam_PasDiadematidae/Sp_03/DSCF0638.JPG

 Invertebrates/Phylum_echinoderma/Class_Holothuroidea/Fam_Stichopodidae:
 Sp_07

 Invertebrates/Phylum_echinoderma/Class_Holothuroidea/Fam_Stichopodidae/Sp_07:
 Invertebrates/Phylum_echinoderma/Class_Holothuroidea/Fam_Stichopodidae/Sp_07/DSCF0724.JPG
```

I did'nt found a way to explain to bash "the last line before" that contain "/Sp*".
This is my code:

```
 # Find the .JPG pattern and catch the picture name ("(.*\).JPG") and add "the last line before" that contain "/Sp*" and reput the .JPG pattern with the picture name:
 sed 's/\(.*\).JPG/"the last line before" that contain "/Sp*""\1.JPG/' list.txt > list2.txt
 sed -e 's/\:/\//g' list2.txt > list3.txt
```

Any advice to help me to complete this part of code is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just find all `.jpg` files that are in an `Sp` folder and output the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are be a better alternative for getting the list of files, if that is not an option, for you specific problem if would write a simple bash script.

```
prefix=""
outfile=list2.txt
> $outfile  # clean any existing file content, remove if not expected
while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ (.*):$ ]]; then
        echo $line >> $outfile
        prefix="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    elif [[ $line =~ \.JPG$ ]]; then
        echo "${prefix}/${line}" >> $outfile
    else
        echo "${line}" >> $outfile
    fi
done < list.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you are actually looking for a way to find all files in this folder and all sub-folders and get the full path to them. If that is the case you should use `find` instead of `ls`. Like:

```
find .
```

or if you do want the full path from root you could do:

```
find /home/yourname/thedirectory/you/are/looking/in
```

Comment: You could use `$(pwd)` for the second sample. And OP is looking for `.JPG` specifically from what I understand, so you might want to add a `-name '*.JPG'` predicate

Comment: Yes if you are looking at the current directory, but you could just as well specify any arbitrary path. You could even use wildcards or any other thing expanded by your shell. Say, all users starting with the letter `p`: `find /home/p*`

Answer (score 1):

if your data in 'd' file, try gnu sed:

```
sed -E '/Sp_[0-9]+:$/{h;p;:c N;/\.JPG$/{s!:\n\s*!/!p;g;bc}; z}' d
```

Answer (score 0):

Although misguided, it is possible to do with `sed` :

```
sed -n -e '/:$/{p;s@:$@/@;h}' -e '/\.JPG$/{H;x;h;s/\n//;p;x;s/\n.*//;h}'
```

You can try it [here](https://ideone.com/vnPBTy#stdout).

The first expression is used when a directory is encountered (based on the fact that the line ends with `:`), prints it and saves the directory path in the hold buffer after having replaced the `:` by the `/` path-separator.

The second expression is used when a `.JPG` file is encountered, and does this sequence of action :

- appends the line to the hold buffer (pattern space : `picture.JPG` ; hold buffer : `dir/\npicture.JPG`)
- exchange the pattern space and the hold buffer (pattern space : `dir/\npicture.JPG` ; hold buffer : `picture.jpg`)
- saves the pattern space to the hold buffer (pattern space : `dir/\npicture.JPG` ; hold buffer : `dir/\npicture.JPG`)
- removes the linefeed from the pattern space (pattern space : `dir/picture.JPG` ; hold buffer : `dir/\npicture.JPG`)
- prints the pattern space (buffers unchanged)
- exchange the hold buffer and pattern space (pattern space : `dir/\npicture.JPG` ; hold buffer : `dir/picture.JPG`)
- removes the linefeed and what follows from the pattern space (pattern space : `dir/` ; hold buffer : `dir/picture.JPG`)
- saves the pattern space to the hold buffer (pattern space : `dir/` ; hold buffer : `dir/`)